# wicked_pdf adding grey box to pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

You can see the problem in the image below. Here is my code:

```
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => false }
      format.pdf do
        render  :pdf =>             "Ticket",
                :no_background =>   true,
                :layout =>          false
      end
    end
  end
```

**Show.pdf.erb** contains one line: `hello`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create the proper HTML formatting to get this to work correctly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />

  </head>
  <body style="background-color:white;">
    <div id="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      hello
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your css:

```
@media print {  
    body { background-color: #FFF; }  
}
```

Comment: I think the problem was not creating an actual HTML file inside show.pdf.erb ... See my answer. Also, your answer would probably work for me, if I was importing CSS styling.. However, I am not.

Comment: Looks like an acceptable attempt at an answer - if you don't like it, the proper move is to downvote it, not flag it.